# "This element is not expected" while using 'any' with xhtml namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xmllint

I have some issues with XML Schema. I need to put some HTML code in my XML file and I found that xs:any would help. But xmllint return me errors like this:

```
example.xml:4: element h1: Schemas validity error : Element 'h1': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}* ).
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
<bar>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</bar>
</foo>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bar" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema says that each `bar` element can contain one element that is in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, but in the instance document you have used an element named `h1` that is in *no* namespace. You need to either put `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the `h1`, or put a prefix declaration further up the tree (e.g. `<foo xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`) and then use that prefix on the XHTML elements (`<h:h1>`).

Comment: I just add a prefix declaration in the <foo /> and it works without prefixes as well.